# css in pentaho table component

Tags: css, layout, pentaho

Good morning,
A very simple question, I have created an expandable table  consisting of the main table and the two secondary tables. What happens to me is that I want them to show in staircase mode (the main total width, the second smallest and aligned to the right and the third to the right and smaller). I do not know where to put the css code. In the layout panel I have to put a css class for a column? then where do I put the css code that refers to those classes?
Thank you very much
[image]

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow. [Please take the time to read how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i haven't got any code of css because i 'don't know where and how i have to put this code But i inserted an image to explain the siotuation. 
the tables in red is what I have now, the green what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the table `margin-left` using `CSS :nth-child() Selector` or by adding a `class`, as shown below

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td,
table th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* staircase style */
table:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
table:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th>header 3</th>
    <th>header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content 1</td>
    <td>content 2</td>
    <td>content 3</td>
    <td>content 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th>header 3</th>
    <th>header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content 1</td>
    <td>content 2</td>
    <td>content 3</td>
    <td>content 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th>header 3</th>
    <th>header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content 1</td>
    <td>content 2</td>
    <td>content 3</td>
    <td>content 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, but where i have to put this code in pentaho cde? i don't know where i have to put this.

Comment: never used `pentaho`, hence can't help there

Answer (score 0):

In the layout panel, there is an option for Add Resource.
[Layout structure options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpv48.png)

Choose to add a CSS resource. You can also select a CSS file. The benefit of a file is that you can keep your formatting consistent across multiple dashboards if you decide to change the CSS at sometime in the future.